# How to design those queries on existing table

Tags: sql, database, select, sqlite

Currently I have some **existing tables** about user action and user info and their associated meta info:

**action table:**

```
user_id, action_detail
1        "action_click"
2        "action_drag"
```

**user info tablle**

```
user_id, full_name, email
1        "User One" "userone@user.com"
1        "User Two" "usertwo@user2.com"
```

**company info table**

```
company_name,      company_domain
"User Company"     "user.com"
"User2 Company"    "user2.com"
```

The new requirement I got is:

Building queries that can find **all the actions of**:

1. all users from a single company
2. a single company but exclude certain users specified
3. multiple companies together but exclude certain users specified

Could anyone give some thoughts about it( especially what is the efficient way to do 2 and 3)?

Comment: What [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @Mureinik sqlite3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Requirement #2 is a subset of requirement #3 (a single company is just a list of companies with the size of one). You could use the `exists` operator to find users under the companies domain, and exclude users based on other conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM   user u
WHERE  full_name NOT IN ('John Doe', 'Jane Doe' /* or any other condition */) AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   company c
               WHERE  c.company_name NOT IN ('company1', 'company2', /* etc. */) AND
                      u.email LIKE '%@' || c.company_domain)
```

**EDIT:**

To address the conversation in the comments, if you have a large number of ignored users, you may want to have an auxiliary table of ignored users so you can index them and make the search faster.

E.g.:

```
CREATE TABLE ignored_users (
  full_name VARCHAR PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO ignored_users VALUES ('John Doe');
-- A bunch of other inserts...
SELECT *
FROM   user u
WHERE  full_name NOT IN (SELECT full_name FROM ignored_users) AND
       EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   company c
               WHERE  c.company_name NOT IN ('company1', 'company2', /* etc. */) AND
                      u.email LIKE '%@' || c.company_domain)
```

Comment: Thanks Man!!  As absolute beginner( I have no idea how SQL works behind the scene), I am just a little bit concerning about **NOT IN**, the excluded user list could be up to 100 and number of company is currently more than 100, will this query be very slow(since the list is still growing)?

Comment: @Kuan you need to pass the excluded way **somehow**. Using `not in` shouldn't be a problem,  but if you see that it is, you can always create an auxiliary table of ignored users and index it.

Comment: Thanks,  once I create an auxiliary table of ignored users, how that helps improve the performance?

Comment: @Kuan in that case searching if a user is in the ignored list can be done by the index, instead of having to check all the users in the list one by one. But again, for a list of a hundred users, or even several hundred users I doubt this would be worth the effort.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I understand it a little bit more: so conceptually, the aux table indexing basically turn the NOT IN operation from O(n) into O(1)? BTW, could you give an example of aux table version in this answer?

Comment: @Kuan it's probably closed to O(log(n)), but yes, that's the gist of it. See my edited answer with an example of how that would be done.

Comment: Thanks so much. Is that indexing automatically done once we create that ignored_users table( so the SELECT full_name FROM ignored_users will be O(logn) )?

Comment: @Kuan the index is implicitly created since `full_name` is a primary key (i.e., it's unique and not null).